# Viscosity setting not showing in blender 4.1

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to work with fluid simulation in Blender 4.1, but I can't seem to find the option for viscosity. I've looked through the physics settings, but it's not clear where I should adjust viscosity parameters.

[image]

Can anyone provide guidance on where to find and adjust viscosity settings in Blender 4.1's fluid simulation?"

Comment: It appears when opening the diffuse part. I've found nothing in the release notes about that. Maybe a UI bug as the "Viscosity" part is not really inside the "Diffuse" part.

Comment: @lemon But in the [Blender 4.1 manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/liquid/diffusion.html) it is a subchapter of _Diffusion_. And if you take a closer look, other sub-categories in the UI are also not "inside" their parent categories. For example _Border Collisions_ under _Settings_ or _Advanced_ under _Cache_ etc. so it is not accidentally happening for the viscosity setting alone, it is everywhere in the domain settings. If that's an error or intentional I do not know, but the viscosity is intentionally under _Diffusion_.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 4.1 you will find it now under *Liquid* > *Diffusion* and it is renamed to *High Vicosity Solver*. I have not made any liquid simulations since then, as far as I know the viscosity solver has not only be renamed but also reworked, so I cannot say if the settings you used in previous versions will give similar results in the new version.

[image: high viscosity solver]